# OPC DA dll compatible with MS KB5004442

Tags: python, opc, dcom, open-opc

I have an Python application that use OpenOPC to connect to our OPC Server. After the release of the Microsoft [KB5004442 DCOM security patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c) this application is not been able to connect. This is because this OpenOPC module make use of an OPC Automation wrapper from [gray-box](http://www.gray-box.net/) which don't have the appropriate security level to be compatible with this new patch. I also suspect that they don't support this dll anymore. I would like to know it anyone else is strugglling with this problem.

I tried to use OPCDAAuto.dll from OPC Foundation but I find out that this was not maintained for a long time so it has the same problem.

I suppose that there are only two option here:

1. Find a dll that is compatible with this new security demand.
2. Use OPC tunnelers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes security patches are an issue with this legacy technologies.

There is a new version of open-opc called [openopc2](https://github.com/iterativ/openopc2) (Disclaimer I am a contributor of the library). It is much easier to install, and its python 3.

Openopc support OPC tunneling wia the opc gateway so that might be a workaround for you.

[Here](https://github.com/iterativ/openopc2/discussions/47) you find a discussion about that exact topic that you mentioned.